# Failed file upload file with Curl and http/3: got Error 55

Tags: curl, http3, openlitespeed

I am trying to upload a file with curl and http/3, but I run into this error. I got:

> - Pass on 30071 body bytes to quiche
> - Pass on 15556 body bytes to quiche
> - Connection #0 to host server.ftn.kg.ac.rs left intact curl: (55) Failed sending data to the peer

I use openlitespeed on server.

the command I used was:

```
curl -v -F 'file1=@c.jpg' https://server-url/upload1.php --http3
```

Is there anything I could try, or maybe all this is due to the fact the http3's support is not so polished yet?

update: the upload is ok if the file is pretty small - with 3.6 KB it went fine

Comment: That's interesting.  Have you compiled curl yourself?  There are two underlying HTTP/3 implementations -- quiche and ngtcp2.  You should try the other one.  https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/HTTP3.md

Comment: Yes, I compiled it in order to enable http3 feature. I know about other options, but I did not manage to make it work otherwise than with cloudflare quiche. (I compiled it on Raspberry with Raspbian)

Comment: I see! And what version of OpenLiteSpeed are you using?

Comment: The version is 1.6.17